# Dennett vs Sapolsky on free will: A clash over different claims?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, free-will, determinism, compatibilism

On a recent Youtube episode of [*Theories of Everything with Curt Jaimungal*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GsaXhVRvuZ4) Daniel Dennett, author and Professor of Philosophy at Tufts University in Massachusetts, discusses his views of Robert Sapolsky's recent work around free will. Sapolsky has been doing the rounds of webcasters to promote his new book, *Determined: a Science of Life Without Free Will* amd is Professor of biology, neurology, neurological sciences, and neurosurgery at Stanford University.

Dennett states (00:00:10):

> "Robert makes one big mistake and it's right at the centre of his work...What he's missed is the difference between control an causation".

Dennett then describes a boulder crashing down a mountain. He states the boulder is caused to do this by "...wind pressure, bumps on the way, material, etc, etc".

> "Now, if we rewound the tape of life and replayed the tape of that exact circumstance, it would roll in exactly the same way. That's determinism".

He then compares the boulder's journey with that of a skier who skis down the mountain. The skier differs from the boulder, claims Dennett, in that she is in *control*.

> "Now the path of the boulder is determined. The path of the skier is determined. The difference is that the skier's path is controlled. The rock's path is not".

> "If you make the distinction between control and causation, then Sapolsky's argument simply falls apart".

[To give some insight into what Sapolsky's position is - and I hope I'm doing him justice here - he invokes a determinism that extends back to the Big Bang in order to deny free will].

Dennett continues:

> "...it doesn't go back to the Big Bang. Because once life gets started...life generates controllers. It generates self-controlled little agents. Things that are alive".

He then goes on to focus on the notion of predictability and how "indeterminism is not required for unpredictability". He states that being unpredictable - whilst still being determined - gives us freedom as agents in the sense that it protects us from other agents. He also states that **"...determinism doesn't prevent you from acting locally, and making your own choices and not being controlled by the past"**.

This is where he confuses me. He is asserting control from determined agents. [I have a feeling this what he came to loggerheads with Sam Harris about in their pub debate following Harris's release of his book 'Free Will').

**How can there be control within a determined sequence of events? Isn't this merely the *illusion* of control?**.

"Evolution pseudo-randomly makes a lot of mutations and the ones that survive survive because they do things that the competition doesn't do, and this", he says, "is what gives them a kind of control; a kind of reliability".

Jaimungal asks Dennett what Sapolsky's reaction to his basic position was. Dennett paraphrases Sapolsky as saying, "No, no. You're still determined by the events going back to before your birth".

He then goes on to give a 'parable of the bathtub' as a means of describing that we "...are reliable in spite of variations in our past". I can only assume that he is referring obliquely to the patterns of behaviour we form as identities that have evolved over time, but I still don't see how this gets us any closer to free will.

**Am I correct in concluding that Dennett and Sapolsky are at odds in relation to very different views of free will? Ie: That Sapolsky is denying the free will that would somehow overcome determinism whereas Dennett is happy with a free will that bestows an illusion of control?**

Comment: I don't think that humans have words and concepts sufficient to ever resolve the question to everyone's satisfaction. I actually don't think that humans ever will, so it becomes yet another pointless debate. Nonduality resolves it nicely.

Comment: @scottrowe. Maybe. Maybe not. It might make things more difficult if the leading minds can't agree on terms. Then again, maybe the diversity of approaches might make it more likely that we'll stumble upon the trutg.

Comment: I seem to recall Sapolsky saying basically that we have no free will but we have to do all the things we are doing either way, for example: criminals can't help committing crimes, so they don't 'deserve' to be imprisoned, yet we can't have them out there harming people. If a concept leads to the same result whether it is true or false, don't we have a word for that? *inoperative* or something? Let's start using that word. **A lot.**

Comment: *To give some insight into what Sapolsky's position is - and I hope I'm doing him justice here - he invokes a determinism that extends back to the Big Bang in order to deny free will* - WHAT?! I must be misunderstanding something here, because that claim is blatantly false. It presupposes that classical mechanics can explain the entire Universe, which was disproved a long time ago. Randomness entailed by quantum mechanics might not allow free will - still they introduce nondeterminism?! One cannot say that all events have been determined since the Big Bang!

Comment: It's possible that no small part of the disagreement is [just semantics](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/compatibilism)

Comment: I agree with @Him, I think they mean slightly different things by their words. In addition it seems Sapolsky assumes something like a deterministic/clockwork universe, and Dennet does not.

Comment: Sapolsky's argument, though I haven't read him describe it in precisely these words, is that free will is so constrained by the factors he has described in his several books as to be trivial. That isn't too awfully far from Dennett's own take on free will as I understand it.

Answer (score 6):

Great question, well posed.

Dennett is the clearest champion of Compatibilism about free-will. Many scientists take from the fact human actions must be reducible to atoms and the void, that we only need the latter for a full account, and any appearance of causal power by agents is so subsumed by the causal narrative of atoms that we can call free will an illusion. This is like saying literature is an illusion, only letters and words are real.

Biology is constituted of vast chains of contingencies. And we can consider genes as an encoding, an image, of a lineages evolutionary niche. Similary when a large-language-model predicts a next word, it does so not from words and letters, but from a low resolution image of their use across the entire internet. You need to know the abstraction in the system, which shaped the control algorithm, to predict the system.

David Krakauer is Professor of Complex Systems at the Santa Fe Institute. I feel his term 'teleonomic matter' can most clearly reveal why these kind of systems are different. He uses it to describe what the domain of Complex Systems Theory is: that it's systems which get information about their environment, record it, and change their dynamics in some way as a result.

This can provide a truly abstract account of what subjectivity. And crucially, of what an observer is in quantum mechanics, where an observation makes the observed part of the observers wave function, the information about which state quantum system is in goes from being isolated from the observer, into the observer's system. The mixed or coherent state goes from being in the wavefunction of the observed quantum system, effectively into the 'wavefunction of the universe'.

It's an over simplistic view of a deterministic universe, to think that the information that fixes or determines future outcomes is distributed evenly everywhere. Quantum systems make it very clear that is not the case. In the same way, the information to predict the skier is disproportionately localised in their control systems, not the shape of the mountain.

A way to picture the physical significance of an increasingly more accurate control algorithm, is to think how the best abstraction of physics could allow energy life and the technology tree to be recovered even the poorest resources, like a patch of interstellar dust, using only very minimal initial resources like data, a fusion device, and a Von-Neuman machine.

I would point to the similarity to high-sensitivity-to-initial-conditions of classical deterministic systems like say three-body systems, which requires measurements of initial conditions that become increasingly difficult, and ultimately can go below the Planck scale, the limit imposed on investigation by the point where any probe would generate a blackhole. See: [Gargantuan chaotic gravitational three-body systems and their irreversibility to the Planck length](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.04029). Similarly improving control algorithms, can amplify sensitivity to initial conditions, to the point where a patch of cosmic dust could do incredibly improbable things.

Comment: Right, the image of the skier is kind of cool (having skied in the past, I can feel in to it). The motions they make might be more related to music they are listening to or recalling than anything about the external world. I remember singing sometimes when I worked on an assembly line. What about the environment made me sing one song rather than another, or sing at all for that matter? "*I know why the caged bird sings*"

Comment: @ScottRowe: They might be focused on completing the slalom faster, rather than simply finding a stable equilibrium on route to maximising entropy. For a stone all we need is the latter to predict it. For the former, goals & intentions & an implementation of control towards attaining them are a far better predictor, even though as we know for the total system the 2nd law of Thermodynamics is not being broken.

Comment: "*Let the 2nd law of Thermodynamics / Remain Unbroken / By and by, Lord / By and by...*" It's got a beat, you can dance to it, I'll give it a +1

Comment: "Many scientists take from the fact human actions must be reducible to atoms and the void, that we only need the latter for a full account, and any appearance of causal power by agents is so subsumed by the causal narrative of atoms that we can call free will an illusion."  I find this statement dubious, unless by "many" you mean "more than five".

Comment: @Him: Specifically here I meant Sapolsky, Einstein, & the many other scientists who explicitly deny the reality of free will. Not exactly amateurs...

Comment: Perhaps if you meant Sapolsky and Einstein, you should say "Sapolsky and Einstein".  Einstein was possibly one of the last great physicists who was staunchly determinist, vehemently rejecting the Copenhagen interpretation of QM.  Anyway, the phrase "Many" here suggests that maybe you are implying that "a large percentage of" or that there is some correlation between being a scientist and rejecting the notion of free will.  If you did not intend these statements, you might want to consider using more clear language.

Comment: @Him: 'Search for free will pits scientists against philosophers' https://theconversation.com/search-for-free-will-pits-scientists-against-philosophers-6981 'Science Hasn’t Refuted Free Will' https://www.bostonreview.net/articles/christian-list-has-science-refuted-free-will 'The clockwork universe: is free will an illusion?' https://www.theguardian.com/news/2021/apr/27/the-clockwork-universe-is-free-will-an-illusion It **is** common for scientists, by which is overwhelmingly meant physicalist-materialists, to deny free will. I found a survey 14% of evolutionary theorists.

Comment: 86% of scientists agreeing with the concept of free-will sounds like the scientists are firmly in the free-will camp, as a group, to me.

Comment: My experience is that it's higher among neutoscientists, & those involved in computation. Because of thinfs like the Libet experiments showing choices are made by brain states before we are aware of them, discussrf here: 'Why neuroscience does not disprove free will' https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332852316_Why_neuroscience_does_not_disprove_free_will And this on how a typical picture of AI denies space for it to have free will 'The Illusion of Free Will in Modern Machine Learning' https://www.cantorsparadise.com/the-illusion-of-free-will-in-modern-machine-learning-fb921cfe0c92

Comment: And related: 'PhilPapers Survey 2020, Why do so many physicalists deny consciousness of future AI systems?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90841/philpapers-survey-2020-why-do-so-many-physicalists-deny-consciousness-of-future/90847#90847

Comment: @Him: You seemed to want numbers. 7% didn't answer. As I say, evolutionary theorists is one thing. But my experience is neuroscientists & programmers are majority free will sceptics. I just can't find survey evidence to back that up. It's about a common picture of physicalist-materialism, & a lack of clarity among many scientists, like say Francis Crick, about what philosophers mean by free will. Eg 'Francis Crick’s Deliberately Provocative Reductionism' https://philosophynow.org/issues/130/Francis_Cricks_Deliberately_Provocative_Reductionism

Answer (score 2):

Both debaters are wrong.  Our universe is not determined.  PARTS of it may be mostly determined, but QM is indeterminate, and chaos theory shows how uncertainties can leverage into the macro scale.

Dennett's conception of a controlling skier is partly correct.  Once we have an idea in our heads of what to do, then the guiding of our bodies IS deterministic.

But the idea itself, if one is a physicalist, AND committed to the random/determined dichotomy, is most plausibly seen as the result of a semi chaotic process, where QM effects in the interaction of our neural system produce random events, which then get sorted by the inherent structure of our neurology into poor, good or better choices.  MAYBE this is what Dennett means.  But then he would be a semi=randomist, not a compatibilist determinist.

If one is a spiritual dualist, or an agent emergentist, then the origin of ideas, OR the selection between them, can have a spiritual or emergent plane component too, which would matrix with the random then bounded/sorted chaotic neurology.

Comment: Dennett explicitly rejects this kind of 'free will of the gaps'. Whether addressing deterministic or random systems, they obey laws, which can account for all the causation. Dennett is a Compatibilist, who accepts this *but also* says we can meaningfully talk about agents with control systems as parts of the physicalist-materialist causal processes.

Comment: "QM is indeterminate" this is only the Copenhagen interpretation.  There are other interpretations of QM that are deterministic.

Comment: @CriglCragl -- a semi-randomist can accept bounded randomness that satisfies physics in chaotic systems that our bounded neuro-inclinations then react to deterministically.  I don't know any other way to argue for a skier being any different from a rock.

Comment: @Him -- the only interpretation with any appreciable support that is deterministic is Bohmian Mechanics -- and that has been failing several tests cases vs Coopenhagen.  Everett isn't deterministic -- what outcome you will see for a quantum event is still random, even if other "you"s will see other outcomes.  Everett is just Coopenhagen with other worlds added too.

Comment: "has been failing several test cases" {{Citation Needed}}

Comment: @Him: Not deterministic - *within the domain of experiment. Many Worlds is deterministic, but only considered across a multiverse that is inaccessible to experiment. Bohmian Mechanics is deterministic, but only in terms of the 'wavefunction of the universe', ie once all the information is brought together, which for the universe as a whole means somehow standing outside of it. We either have to abandon local realism, or hidden variables, ie Bells Theorem, & the overwhelming consensus among physicists is that it has to be the latter

Comment: @CriglCragl Unfortunately, the gold standard in Empiricism is experiment, and not very-smart-folks' opinions on the subject.  AFAIK, there have been no successful experiments to distinguish between Copenhagen and Pilot Wave, for example.  [Follow here for possible updates on this subject](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/133906/are-different-interpretations-of-quantum-mechanics-empirically-distinguishable).  Anyway, I suspect that many physicists' opinions on the matter are not as strong as you suspect, and are more about which mathematical framework is most convenient.

Comment: @Him Link: https://settheory.net/Bohm  Also https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/68224/deterministic-or-stochastic-universe/88579#88579  Bohm has a lot of problems, most notably that it is theoretically uncalculable, as every particle in the universe has causal influence on every reaction, but much of our universe is outside our light cone, so we have no idea what particles are even there.  Your Physics SE link was mostly referencing Wikipedia, which is an unreliable reference.

Comment: Bohm himself explicitly didn't take his approach seriously, but as a way to point to other ways to reconcile the constraints of Bell's Theorem. I'd look to the proposed but not proven law of Conservation of Information, which was called on to solve the Blackhole Paradox, as providing a clearer model of what is meant by Determinism - the unfolding of events according to physical laws, which are reversible & alliw the past to be specified

Comment: It's not the case that "the only interpretation" is Bohm's. There is also superdeterminism, and while whether that has "appreciable support" is subjective, that's irrelevant, since it is an interpretation and works perfectly well, although like Bohm's it makes no different predictions. ... Further it is not in principle possible to prove the universe is not deterministic - even copenhagen-like wavefunction collapses could be following some script, even if such a script is not accessible to us and therefore useless.

Comment: It's true that Bohm/superdeterminism are uncalculable, but that has no bearing on whether they are true or not. It is not a given that it is possible for us to answer every question.

Comment: @Ben -- superdeterminism is untestable in principle.  https://mateusaraujo.info/2019/12/17/superdeterminism-is-unscientific/  Per Popper's boundary criteria, it is pseudo-scientific.  Great Deceiver hypotheses are never refutable, and assigning the role of deceiver to the universe rather than God or a Demon or an AI writer -- does not make them any less of an ultimate conspiracy theory.  Bohm is a hypothesis, not an interpretation.  Bohm has had failed predictions -- the data is trending strongly against Bohm.

Comment: I don't disagree, superdeterminism is untestable. I think I said that it was uncalculable which at least in practice is the same thing. That does not mean it is not correct. I agree it fails Popper's boundary criteria, so it is not disprovable but that also does not mean it is not correct. This is not the same as saying that it is not correct: "even copenhagen-like wavefunction collapses could be following some script, even if such a script is not accessible to us and therefore useless".

Comment: @Ben I treat “this idea requires a Great Deceiver” as even more wrong than “this idea is explicitly falsified”.  After all, we could be wrong about the falsification.

Comment: There is no great deceiver in superdeterminism. It is a horrible and frightening proposition to be sure, but not for that reason.

Comment: @Ben. The thesis of super determinism  is that the universe structures itself to only look indeterminate— the outcome of all quantum effects is preset to be entirely self consistent with randomness.  The universe is LIKE a Great Deceiver, but accomplishes this Great Deception without agency.  If anything, it is even less plausible than a Great Deceiver, because for them there is some reason behind the deception.  For SuperDeterminism there is no reason at all.

Comment: I don't think that's quite right. As I understand it the thesis is essentially like a clockwork universe, but with the provisio that we cannot see all of the clockwork - I.e. the speed of light prevents us having access to the information which would allow us to *predict* the event until after it is too late, but that it is nonetheless clockwork.

Comment: It's useless in a way as it can't be distinguished from Copenhagen type nondeterminism. I think it has no philosophical consequences for that reason - it cannot compel us to change our beliefs - so we should be sanguine about it.

Comment: To be clear with my physics hat on, I don't think it can ever be proved either way whether the universe is deterministic at the quantum level. The best physics could do is show that physics is or is not consistent with determinism.

Comment: But that would not do - even if the laws of physics seem to be deterministic when we are looking, that would not prove that little miracles did not occur when we didn't look - our mortal bodies could still be controlled by our immortal soul. Conversely, if it physics seems nondeterministic, then there could still be a Great Script.

Comment: I hope you would agree that we should act as if we have free will, even if we cannot prove we do. I am only commenting to disagree on your characterisation of the physics.

Comment: @Ben You are just asserting Duhem-Quine.  For every theory, one can somehow patch it to account for all evidence.  There IS no such patch been offered for SuperDeterminism -- just Duhem-Quine is being claimed, that there COULD be such a theory.  Additionally, SuperDeterminism asserts that all such patches are UNOBSERVABLE IN PRINCIPLE -- IE untestable, and therefore outside of science.  This is just the same rationale used for Long Dream, and Great Deceiver, but without an agent.  It is dismissible as Not Even Wrong, and pseudoscience.

Answer (score 1):

> "...determinism doesn't prevent you from acting locally, and making
> your own choices and not being controlled by the past".

This statement makes no sense. Determinism means that everything is caused/controlled by the past. There are no agents capable of self-determining their own actions.

> How can there be control within a determined sequence of events?

You have reached the main problem with Dennett's compatibilism: How an action can be determined by **both** the agent herself **and** the past events? I don't know how he explains this, but it is quite obvious that he must redefine **both** free will (=agent determines) **and** determinism (=past events determine) beyond recognition.

There cannot be any control within a determined sequence of events. Nor can there be any evolution or anything random (pseudo- or true).

The problem with both gentlemen is that they are both trying to shoehorn determinism into reality.

Comment: Yes, and the shoe doesn't fit, because determinism is too small. Cinderella has big feet.

Comment: Why can there not be anything pseudo-random? (I would define that as deterministic, but sufficiently obscure as to appear random to an observer unaware of the algorithm, but perhaps you are using a different definition.)

Comment: @Oddthinking Pseudo-randomness is not deterministic as pseudo-randomness is literally *fake* randomness. Determinism cannot fake anything, faking requires free will.

Comment: I disagree on both counts. Pseudo-randomness is fake randomness precisely because it *is* deterministic (but doesn't appear to be). More importantly, if faking implies free will, and fake things exist, then there must be free will, and the entire issue is resolved!

Comment: @Oddthinking You don't seem to understand the concept of randomness. In a deterministic system there is no randomness at all, fake or true, everything is determined with absolute accuracy. True randomness requires a truly stochastic process. Fake randomness requires someone to deliberately decide the values in order to give an impression of randomness.

Comment: @Oddthinking There is no issue to be resolved. Free will is a matter of definition and most definitions mean the ability to make decisions.

Comment: Thank you. You've made it clear you don't use conventional definitions, and thus I can ignore your conclusions.

Comment: @Oddthinking What would be the conventional definitions then? What conclusions are you talking about?

Comment: How can you address the arguments if you are not interested in what they are? What Dennett thinks is exactly the question.

Comment: @CriglCragl We know what Dennett thinks and we know that it is not logically possible without redefining both free will and determinism.

Comment: An ATM makes decisions. By your definition, it has free will. Conversely, you reject pseudo-randomness because in a deterministic world, there is no-one who can make decisions? Randomness is normally defined by the lack of predictability and patterns (or alternatively the lack of compressibility). Meanwhile, the [problem of Free Will](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_will) seems to still exist even [on this site](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free-will).

Comment: @Oddthinking Machines cannot make any decisions. Programmers decide everything a computer does. I do not reject pseudo-randomness, *determinism* rejects it (=assumes nonexistent). "Random" has many meanings in different contexts, but in this context "random" means unintended, not deliberately decided. Thus pseudo-randomness is intentional, deliberately decided to look like random.

Comment: To predict an ATM, you only need minimal info about button-pressing & bank balances, & the control algorithm. Predicting it disproportionately depends on information in the control system. The skiier is like this, even though just like the rock they obey the laws of physics. Causation is lumpy, & minds concentrate it so much that the future state of the lightcone of species like ours will pivotally depend on what control systems they have, eg how well they understand & can manipulate the world.

Comment: @PerttiRuismäki: I don't get to demand you use certain definitions. I do get to ignore your conclusions if you choose weird ones.

Answer (score 1):

Dennett's thoughts are consistent with the overall philosophical landscape and with free will too, as we understand it that is. Sapolsky has a point too and his skiing example is apposite.

At times like these I suggest we employ our knowledge or wisdom, if possible, and, let's not forget, imagination. There's a boulder, there's a skier; both on a hilltop. What follows has a structure to it and we conduct, either a *gedanken experiment* or carry out a *scientific experiment*.

Comment: I think there is a good point to be unpacked there. The skier has a mental landscape of possible futures, the processing of which according to control systems like 'skill acquired at skiing' will shape the actions of the skiier. A rock will fall in different ways depending on how similar we can make the initial conditions & the landscape; but it will be a far smaller landscape of variations than repeated runs of the skiier.

Comment: @CriglCragl, bingo! We're in good hands, oui monsieur?